# I need to split json data

Tags: json

I want to modify the current JSON file with the following change:

I want to edit the "Vs" column and split that data into two columns. I want it to be split into two columns named team 1 and team 2 respectively by splitting data after 'vs'.

How should I do that using python script?

Input: JSON data (this is sample data.)

```
[
 {
   "Match No": "1",
   "Date": "17-10-21",
   "Vs": "Sri Lanka vs Ireland",
   "Rounds": "1st",
   "Group": "Group A"
 },
```

Required Output: JSON data

```
[
 {
   "Match No": "1",
   "Date": "17-10-21",
   "Team1": "Sri Lanka",
   "Team2": "Ireland",
   "Rounds": "1st",
   "Group": "Group A"
 },
```

Comment: Be more clear how you want to achieve this. Which language do you want to use?

Comment: I want to achieve this using python script.

Comment: Read, modify, write. Simple as that. Those are also three steps you can take in isolation. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, you can use the searchbar to find existing questions concerning JSON handling in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I used the library json to serialize your input. THen you only need to loop over each object in the json array and create a new json object from the data. I hope you understand the principal.

```
import json

input = """

[
 {
   "Match No": "1",
   "Date": "17-10-21",
   "Vs": "Sri Lanka vs Ireland",
   "Rounds": "1st",
   "Group": "Group A"
 }
 ]

"""

result = json.loads("""
[
]
""")

for o in json.loads(input):
    teams = o["Vs"].split(" vs ")
    result.append({
        "Match No": o["Match No"],
        "Date": o["Date"],
        "Team 1": teams[0],
        "Team 2": teams[1],
        "Rounds": o["Rounds"],
        "Group": o["Group"]
    })


print(result)
```